# WatchService throwing ClosedWatchServiceException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, watchservice

I am using java.nio.file.WatchService to watch a directory in my Spring boot application. I am getting the following exception all the time and it does not seem like it is detecting any file changes in the watched folder:

```
java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException: null
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.checkOpen(AbstractWatchService.java:80)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take(AbstractWatchService.java:117)
at com.company.MyFilesMonitor.monitorMappingFiles(MyMappingFilesMonitor.java:27)
at com.company.MyFilesMonitor$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3d959079.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Below is the code that creates the bean:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.ClassUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Configuration
public class MyFilesMonitorConfiguration {
    @Value("${company.integration.converter.mapper-files:mappers}")
    private String mapperFilesLocation;

    @Bean
    public WatchService mappingFilesWatch() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        URL url = Objects.requireNonNull(ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()).getResource(mapperFilesLocation);
        try(WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
            Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
            if (!Files.isDirectory(path)) {
                // ToDo: i18n
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid mapping files path" + path);
            }
                path.register(
                        watchService,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
                        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE
                );
            return watchService;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the class that uses the watchService bean:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.nio.file.*;

@Service
public class MyMappingFilesMonitor {
    private final WatchService watchService;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyMappingFilesMonitor.class);

    @Autowired
    public MyMappingFilesMonitor(WatchService watchService) {
        this.watchService = watchService;
    }

    @Async
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void monitorMappingFiles() {
        final WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                final WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                if (kind == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) {
                    continue;
                }
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                final WatchEvent<Path> watchEventPath = (WatchEvent<Path>) event;
                final Path filename = watchEventPath.context();
                System.out.println("******** kind: " + kind + " -> " + filename);
                key.reset();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I am missing here. I looked at different sample codes here and there and I am not doing anything different yet I still get this exception all the time. Any help or pointers is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using try with resources to create the new watch service, so it is always closed by the time the method `mappingFilesWatch()` returns it:

```
try(WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService()) {
    ...
    return watchService;  // THIS IS AUTO-CLOSED
}
```

You just need to remove the try block.

Comment: Thanks @DuncG. I will try it and update with the result.